# Linked a SQL to Access, Requery is displaying #Deleted

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, ms-access

I have a SQL Server backend I have linked to a Access frontend.  I recently deleted a table link in Access and relinked it to a View that displays the contents of that deleted table on the SQL side. I then changed the Name in Access of the view to the name the table previously had so that code would work.

The problem is anytime a REQUERY is called, everything that references the old table shows #DELETED.  I'm thinking the code is still somehow linked to the old table, but inserting and deleting data through the view work properly so I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a compact and repair on the Access DB? If I recall that sorted out the #DELETED issue for me previously

Comment: Yea, I've tried that already to no avail.

Comment: Not clear what you currently have. Is the following accurate: Access had link to SQLServer table 'Table1'; you deleted that link and added a link to SQLServer 'View1'. Then in Access, you renamed the link from 'View1' to 'Table1'? What other code is called? Any deletes of data from tables? If you open the 'View1/Table1' object from Access, does everything look OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.  I was being stupid and didn't realize my row level security wasn't being implemented till after a requery, so the record was getting lost.